# What command can I put in the Sword Art Online UI that will run a program with admin privileges?

Tags: windows-8, cmd.exe

I've got this Sword Art Online UI, and I've got Warcraft 3 in it. Both work perfectly with Windows 8, but even on my Windows 7 computer I needed to run wc3 with admin privileges to get on battle.net. If anyone knows a simple CMD to run it with admin privileges please let me know. Here's what I mean:

```
runadmin {adminaccount|adminpassword} program
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If UAC is enabled, there is no way to elevate a non-privileged CMD session - therefore, even with runas, there's no way to use a CMD command to launch an app with Administrator privileges.

What you should do instead, is edit the properties of the program shortcut. On the "Shortcut" tab of the shortcut's Properties dialog, click "Advanced". In the Advanced Properties dialog, check "Run as administrator". Click OK on both dialogs, and try running the program. If UAC is enabled, and you're not using an account that has Administrator privileges, you will be prompted to provide credentials to an Administrator account.

Answer (score 0):

thanks, but i found something, i could post it here or something but basically i would hit the button in the utils and itd run a cmd that asks for a admin password, and if you give it it would save the password untill you shutdown the pc, and it would start the program and if you hit the button while the pass was saved it would just run the game with admin